# Kivy (Python) Problem with AttributeError after add_widget with kv-file

Tags: python, kivy

I'am new in Kivy and have follow problem (Environment is Python 3.7 with Kivy-1.11.1.):

I need a navigation area and a view area (=ViewScreen). With the navigation area i change the view area (change of kv-files - look later at 'def next_screen'). My problem is, that i can't interact with widgets (e.g. 'lblTest') in the view area.
I use follow files:

- testGUI.py (= GUI Application)
- testGUIRoot.kv (= RootWidget as kv-file)
- testGUIBtn1.kv (= view area 1 as kv-file)
- testGUIBtn2.kv (= view area 2 as kv-file)

The GUI Application is simple and starts the GUI and change the view area.
**testGUI.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
   # runs select application
   def startApplication (self, instance):
      print(self.lblTest)

class mainGUI(App):
   def build(self):
      # loading the content of root.kv
      self.root = Builder.load_file('testGUIRoot.kv')

   def next_screen(self, screen):
      #Clear container and load the given screen object from file in kv folder.

      filename = screen + '.kv'
      # unload the content of the .kv file
      # reason: it could have data from previous calls
      Builder.unload_file(filename)

      # clear the container
      self.root.container.clear_widgets()
      # load the content of the .kv file
      screen = Builder.load_file(filename)
      # add the content of the .kv file to the container
      self.root.container.add_widget(screen)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   '''Start the application'''
   mainGUI().run()
```

I use follow kv-files:
**testGUIRoot.kv:**

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

RootWidget:
   container: container
   orientation: 'horizontal'

   # Navigation
   BoxLayout:
      orientation: 'vertical'
      size_hint: (0.35, 1)

      Button:
         text: 'testButton1'
         on_release: root.startApplication(self,)
         on_press: app.next_screen('testGUIBtn1')

      Button:
         text: 'testButton2'
         on_release: root.startApplication(self,)
         on_press: app.next_screen('testGUIBtn2')

   # ViewScreen
   BoxLayout:
      size_hint: (0.65, 1)
      id: container
      orientation: 'vertical'
      padding: 0
      spacing: 3

      Label:
         text: 'no data'
         color: (0.667,0.667,0.667,1)
         font_size: 14
         bold: True
```

**testGUIBtn1.kv:**

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

Label:
   id: lblTest
   text: 'Button 1'
   color: (0.667,0.667,0.667,1)
   font_size: 14
   bold: True
```

**testGUIBtn2.kv:**

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

Label:
   id: lblTest
   text: 'Button 2'
   color: (0.667,0.667,0.667,1)
   font_size: 14
   bold: True
```

Follow error appears:
*AttributeError: 'RootWidget' object has no attribute 'lblTest'*

Have you a solution to interact with the Object 'lblTest'? For example like self.lblTest.text = 'Test-Text'.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

Content of 'def next_screen' of mainGUI(App) to 'def startApplication'. Now i can change widgets in object oScreen or using the object in other python libs.

```
def startApplication (self, instance, sScreen):
   filename = sScreen + '.kv'
   # unload the content of the .kv file
   # reason: it could have data from previous calls
   Builder.unload_file(filename)
   # clear the container
   self.container.clear_widgets()
   # load the content of the .kv file
   oScreen = Builder.load_file(filename)
   # add the content of the .kv file to the container
   self.container.add_widget(oScreen)
   
   print(oScreen.ids.lblTest.text)
```

The follow should be added in kv-files testGUIBtn1.kv, testGUIBtn2.kv:

*RootWidget:*

In kv-file testGUIRoot.kv you have change on_release to

*on_release: root.startApplication(self,'testGUIBtn1')*

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with Kivy just this week, also as a new user.
The thing I have learned is to define properties on your RootWidget, just as the labels you already defined in the .kv files. This 'links' the layout and the Python code to eachother.

First of all you need to import the Kivy ObjectProperty by adding:
`from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty`

Next up is to declare the property on your RootWidget class.
You can add `lblTest = ObjectProperty(None)` right after the class-declaration.

The top of your file testGUI.py should look like this then:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
   # Link the layout objects
   lblTest = ObjectProperty(None)

   # runs select application
   def startApplication (self, instance):
      print(self.lblTest)
```

The page that really helped me with this is https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/kivy-tutorial/object-properties/

A little sidenote is it would be best to keep your `id` attributes fully unique.

Comment: That does not work (this was one of many previous attempts) for me. In the Root Widget ( - look at kv-file) is no widget Label with id "lblTest". The widget is in function next_screen - with loading of a kv-file (e.g. testGUIBtn1.kv). I think, my problem is, that with loading of the kv-file there is no initializing of the widget 'lbtTest' for the Root Widget.

Comment: I will look at the link. Hope i find a solutions for this problem.

Comment: Thanks 'jeroenpeters' for your hint

Comment: The problem at hand looked like you missed the initialisation indeed, so that is why I posted this. This fixed it for me, but did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: So far i have not found a solution. I test this with ObjectProperty, but the Object is only None and would not actualized with add_widget in def next_screen. print(self.lblTest) (in def startApplication) delivers None, when i click a button.

Comment: I can initialze an object in RootWidget of kv-file with lblTest: lblTest. But i need to initialize lblTest of an other kv-file which ist loaded in RootWidget with next_screen. Get I something wrong?